# Visual Studio - Intellij Help shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea

Intellij has the most amazing shortcut ever made - ctrl shift a. I don't know if they invented it or copied it, but it's the best.

Does visual studio code have a similar shortcut? Or (failing that) a plugin that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the "intellij IDEA keybindings" by first pressing "ctrl+shift+x" and then searching.

once installed, this seems to make "ctrl+shift+a" work. I guess now all my key bindings are intellij, but that's a small price to pay - the only one i ever really used was "ctrlshift+a"